# Does Python have a "compile only" switch like Perl's -c?

Tags: python, compiler-construction

Perl has the `-c` switch to compile the code without running it.  This is convenient for debugging compile errors in Perl.

Does Python have a similar switch?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can say

```
python -m py_compile script_to_check.py
```

However, this will have the side effect of creating a compiled `script_to_check.pyc` file in the same directory as your script.  This feature is designed to speed up later uses of a module rather than to make sure that your syntax is correct, though you could certainly use it for that.

Answer (score 9):

Even better is to run [pyflakes](http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodPyflakes), [pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) or maybe [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) at the code. They catch some common errors that compiling won't.

Comment: If you want to catch things like variables used before being set, then pychecker is helpful --- these things are not caught by mere compiling.  I had a bit of trouble getting it to check a module (as opposed to a script), though.  I had to do `pychecker foo.bar foo.bar.baz` because the `foo/bar/baz.py` file uses relative imports.  But once I got it working, it seems to work quite well (e.g., `[system path]/foo/bar/baz.py:123 No global (qix) found`).

Answer (score 0):

Through 2.6, there's [the compiler package](http://docs.python.org/library/compiler.html).  That page doesn't say if there is a replacement in 3.0, or if you just can't do that any more.

Comment: there is a built-in `compile` function http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#compile